# How can I get just one value from a flatList that rander a result from my database

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need get just one of the values from the array that of origin my flat list because I'm building a update screen, so I need get the json of one user, and not all the objects from the array, I try get it with a function, and it works but just on second try, at the first it's return null, and it just don't make any sense to me

```
export default function Pesquisa({navigation}){  
  
 
  const renderItem=({item}) =>{
    

    return (  
      
      <View style={css.containerList}>
      
        <Text> {item.no_completo}</Text> 
        <Text> {formataCPF(String(item.nu_cpf))}</Text>
        <Text> {item.ds_email}</Text> 
        <Text> {formataNumero(item.nu_telefone_completo)}</Text>  
        <TouchableOpacity style={css.button_editar} onPress={()=> navigateEdit(item.no_completo)} > 
        <Text style={css.text_buttom_editar}> EDITAR</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      
      </View>

    )
    
  }
   
  
    const [nu_cpf, setNu_cpf]=useState(null); 
    const [no_completo, setNo_completo]=useState(null); 
    const [data, setData] = useState([]) 
    const [dados, setDados] = useState(null)


    function navigateEdit(selectedItem){ 
     setDados(data.filter(data=> data.no_completo === selectedItem))
    console.log('resutado', dados)


  
      
     
    }
    
  

  
  
    return( 
        <View style={css.containerMenu}>  
        <MenuAreaRestrita title='Pesquisa' navigation={navigation}/>  
        
        <View> 
        <Text style={css.textCadastro}> Preencha um dos campos:</Text>
        </View>
        <TextInput style={css.textInputCadastro} placeholder="Nome completo" onChangeText={text=> setNo_completo(text) }/>
        <TextInputMask style={css.textInputCadastro} type={'cpf'} placeholder="CPF do usuário" onChangeText={text=> setNu_cpf(text) } value={nu_cpf}  />  
        <TouchableOpacity style={css.button_login} onPress={()=> sendForm()} > 
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop:6, alignSelf:'center', fontSize:15, color: '#fff'}}>PESQUISAR PACIENTE</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 


        <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} data={data} keyExtractor={(item)=> String(item.id)} /> 
      
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state to null yourself

```
const [no_completo, setNo_completo]=useState(null);
```

So passing null to navigateEdit method results in null

Your function navigateEdit takes in an item.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={css.button_editar} onPress={()=> navigateEdit(item.no_completo)} >
```

You are executing the function onPress() (which means function is executed when you click on the element)

when you click on the fucntion it is executed,having null value inside as a parameter.
Therefore your

```
setDados(data.filter(data=> data.no_completo === selectedItem))
```

also has null value inside,which results in null on the first click

The solution will be not to set no_complete to null initially and also you do not have to set dados to null

```
const [no_completo, setNo_completo]=useState();
const [dados, setDados] = useState();
```

Comment: this is not about this const, it's about const [dados, setDados] = useState(null), my function should set this, and do, but just on the second try

Comment: so, now it's return undefined and not null